# Python - Path finding. Trying find shortest way when obstacles included

Tags: python, arrays, path, find

Let's say I have array (a[19][19]) like this one:

```html
 [[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  1  1  1 -1 -1  2  2  2  2  2 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1  1  0]
  [ 0  1  1 -1 -1 -1  2  2  2  2  2 -1  1  1 -1  1  1  1  0]
  [ 0  2  2 -1 -1  2  2  2  2  2  2 -1  1  1 -1  1  1  1  0]
  [ 0  2  2 -1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  0]
  [ 0  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2 -1 -1  1  1  1  0]
  [ 0  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2 -1  1  1  1  0]
  [ 0  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  0]
  [ 0  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  0]
  [ 0  2  2 -1  2  2  2  2  2  3  2  2  2  2 -1  2 -1  1  0]
  [ 0  2  2 -1 -1 -1 -1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2 -1  2 -1  2  0]
  [ 0  2  2 -1 -1  1 -1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  0]
  [ 0  2  2 -1 -1  1 -1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2 -1  2 -1  2  0]
  [ 0  2  2 -1  1  1 -1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2 -1  2 -1  2  0]
  [ 0  2  2 -1  1  1 -1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2 -1 -1 -1 -1  0]
  [ 0  2  2 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  0]
  [ 0  2  2 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  0]
  [ 0  2  2 -1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1  1  0]
  [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]]
```

- (3) - Is a player or something that moves.
- (2) - Every spot that is possible to access from middle spot.
- (-1) - Is a point that is not accessible.

So for example I am getting point a[17][1] then I check if this spot = 2. If its fine I can move to next step. I have to find shortest path to given point and I should move like in snake game so I cant jump from one point to another when then touch each other by corner.

Example path from a[9][9] to a[17][1]

```html
path=[[9,9],[9,8],[9,7],[9,6],[9,5],[9,4],[8,4],[8,3],[8,2],[9,2],[10,2],[11,2],[12,2],[13,2],[14,2],[15,2],[16,2],[17,2],[17,1]]
```

Most difficult thing would be when starter point is closed in square that have exit only at North(door) and my destination point is somewhere at South outside this square(room).

I am asking if there are already some tricks/methods that could help me with this? Its getting hard when you have to go in opposite direction from destination to first leave some room or to choose correct path and not get into room like this.

Comment: Look at path-finding algorithms in graphs. Simple BFS works for this case (because all "edges" have the same weight), but read also about Dijkstra (his algorithm, not the person, obviously). Dijkstra's algorithm works for different weights (in case you'll want to modify terrain to have different speeds, or something). And in the future you might want to cut unnecessary tests and the simplest algorithm for that is A*, which is based on Dijkstra.

Comment: This was one of the classical examples for *backtracking*, although given the fact that it would generate all possible options, it might not be the best option here (because it's slow).